# Swift flatMap on array with elements are optional has different behavior

Tags: swift, option-type, type-inference, flatmap

```
let arr: [Int?] = [1,2,3,4,nil]

let arr1 = arr.flatMap { next in
    next
}
// arr1: [1,2,3,4]
let arr2: [Int?] = arr.flatMap { next -> Int? in
   next
}
// arr2: [Optional(1), Optional(2), Optional(3), Optional(4)]
```

I'm confused by these code, why do they make a difference?

update: please see these codes, I

```
let arr: [Int?] = [1,2,3,4,nil]

let arr1: [Int?] = arr.flatMap { next in
    next
}
// arr1: [Optional(1), Optional(2), Optional(3), Optional(4), nil]
let arr2: [Int?] = arr.flatMap { next -> Int? in
    next
}
// arr2: [Optional(1), Optional(2), Optional(3), Optional(4)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Adam says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37505863/2976878), it's due to the explicit type that you're supplying for your result. In your second example, this is leading to confusion caused by double wrapped optionals. To better understand the problem, let's take a look at the `flatMap` function signature.

```
@warn_unused_result
public func flatMap<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T?) rethrows -> [T]
```

When you explicitly specify that the result is of type `[Int?]`, because `flatMap` returns the generic type `[T]` – Swift will infer `T` to be `Int?`.

Now this causes confusion because the closure that your pass to `flatMap` takes an element input and returns `T?`. Because `T` is `Int?`, this closure is now going to be returning `T??` (a double wrapped optional). This compiles fine because types can be freely promoted to optionals, including optionals being promoted to double optionals.

So what's happening is that your `Int?` elements in the array are getting promoted to `Int??` elements, and then `flatMap` is unwrapping them back down to `Int?`. This means that `nil` elements can't get filtered out from your `arr1` as they're getting doubly wrapped, and `flatMap` is only operating on the second layer of wrapping.

Why `arr2` *is* able to have `nil` filtered out of it appears to be as a result of the promotion of the *closure* that you pass to `flatMap`. Because you explicitly annotate the return type of the closure to be `Int?`, the closure will get implicitly promoted from `(Element) -> Int?` to `(Element) -> Int??` (closure return types can get freely promoted in the same way as other types) – rather than the element *itself* being promoted from `Int?` to `Int??`, as without the type annotation the closure would be inferred to be `(Element) -> Int??`.

This quirk appears to allow `nil` to avoid being double wrapped, and therefore allowing `flatMap` to filter it out (not entirely sure if this is expected behaviour or not).

You can see this behaviour in the example below:

```
func optionalIntArrayWithElement(closure: () -> Int??) -> [Int?] {
    let c = closure() // of type Int??
    if let c = c { // of type Int?
        return [c]
    } else {
        return []
    }
}

// another quirk: if you don't explicitly define the type of the optional (i.e write 'nil'),
// then nil won't get double wrapped in either circumstance
let elementA : () -> Int? = {Optional<Int>.None} // () -> Int?
let elementB : () -> Int?? = {Optional<Int>.None} // () -> Int??

// (1) nil gets picked up by the if let, as the closure gets implicitly upcast from () -> Int? to () -> Int??
let arr = optionalIntArrayWithElement(elementA)

// (2) nil doesn't get picked up by the if let as the element itself gets promoted to a double wrapped optional
let arr2 = optionalIntArrayWithElement(elementB)

if arr.isEmpty {
    print("nil was filtered out of arr") // this prints
}

if arr2.isEmpty {
    print("nil was filtered out of arr2") // this doesn't print
}
```

---

#### Moral of the story

Steer away from double wrapped optionals, they can give you super confusing behaviour!

If you're using `flatMap`, then you should be expecting to get back `[Int]` if you pass in `[Int?]`. If you want to keep the optionality of the elements, then use `map` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Well explained!

Comment: This line: ...the closure will get implicitly promoted from `(Element) -> Int?` to `(Element) -> Int??`,should it be corrected as: the closure will get implicitly promoted from `(Element) -> Int?` to (`(Element) -> Int?`?) for more precise?

Comment: @Josscii No it's correct how it is – you're explicitly annotating the closure as `(Element) -> Int?`, but `flatMap` is expecting `(Element) -> T?`. In this case `T` is inferred to be `Int?`, therefore `T?` is `Int??`, so the closure is `(Element) -> Int??`. The closure itself isn't optional, only the return type.

Comment: as you say above, the second transform closure is equal to the first one? They are both `(Element) -> Int??` ?

Comment: @Josscii Types can be freely promoted to optionals, and this applies to closures too, so therefore a `(Element) -> Int?` can be promoted to a  `(Element) -> Int??`. In the same way a `() -> Int` can be promoted to a `() -> Int?`. In this example you're creating a `(Element) -> Int?`, but `flatMap` is expecting a `(Element) -> Int??`. This isn't a problem though as the closure you create can be promoted.

Comment: Understood, thanks again. I'll look more from you code example.

Comment: Sorry for asking here it may be duplicate . `var newTemp : [[Int]?] = [[123],nil,[456]]` now `var output = newTemp.flatMap{$0}`  it shows `[[123], [456]]` not `[123,456]` why ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya There are two flavours of `flatMap` on sequences; one that flattens out sequences returned from the closure passed to it, and one that filters out nils from the closure passed to it (note this overload is soon to be renamed to `compactMap` to avoid confusion). In your example, you’re using the nil filtering overload, so the nils in your array are filtered out. It won’t however do any flattening of the nested arrays. You could call `flatMap` again to achieve that.

Comment: @Hamish You are awesome !!

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the explicit type you are giving `arr2`. When you specify that `arr2` must be of type `[Int?]`, Swift complies and simply wraps the values in an optional. However, the `flatMap` operation returns the non-nil values of the array, which makes it obvious as to why `arr1` is of type `[Int]`. To see that `flatMap` returns the non-nil values of the array just look at the declaration notes of the function. Also, if you understand what the `flatMap` operation does in general use, which is that it unwraps the inner wrapping of values, you can see why the function returns a value of type `[Int]`. Consider `arr`, which is of type `[Int?]`. Rewriting the type of `arr` in its wrapped form, it becomes `Array<Optional<Int>>`. For the `flatMap` function to unwrap the inner wrapping, the function must return a value of type `Array<Int>`. To do this, the function must throw out nil values.

Comment: I don't know if you notice the difference of the trailing transform function parameter and return type, the second explicitly write out the return type is (Int?) , but the first one not, this is the part I can't figure out why mostly.

Comment: The return types for both transforms are identical. The only difference is one is implied. The cause of the different types of the two arrays is the explicit type given before the assignment (`=`) operator in the second case.

Comment: For `arr1`, the return type of the transform is easily inferred by Swift because it knows you are returning a value of type `Int?`.

Comment: why arr1 didn't fliter the nil?