# flatMap does not filter out nil when ElementOfResult is inferred to be Optional

Tags: swift, functional-programming, option-type, flatmap

Swift documentation of flatMap reads:

> Returns an array containing the non-nil results of calling the given
>   transformation with each element of this sequence.

In the following examples when return type of `ElementOfResult` is left to the compiler to infer `flatMap` works as documented, yet on line 5 when `ElementOfResult` is specified, thus inferred to an `Optional<String>` type it seems that `flatMap` stops filtering out `nil`'s.

Why is it doing that?

```
~ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> let words = ["1989", nil, "Fearless", nil, "Red"]
words: [String?] = 5 values {
  [0] = "1989"
  [1] = nil
  [2] = "Fearless"
  [3] = nil
  [4] = "Red"
}
  2> words.flatMap { $0 }
$R0: [String] = 3 values {
  [0] = "1989"
  [1] = "Fearless"
  [2] = "Red"
}
  3> let resultTypeInferred = words.flatMap { $0 }
resultTypeInferred: [String] = 3 values {
  [0] = "1989"
  [1] = "Fearless"
  [2] = "Red"
}
  4> let resultTypeSpecified: [String?] = words.flatMap { $0 }
resultTypeSpecified: [String?] = 5 values {
  [0] = "1989"
  [1] = nil
  [2] = "Fearless"
  [3] = nil
  [4] = "Red"
}
```

Comment: Remember that `flatMap(_:)` returns `[ElementOfResult]`, and the closure return is of type `ElementOfResult?`. Therefore if you annotate the return as `[String?]`, you're saying that the closure returns `String??`. Thus the optional elements are promoted to double wrapped optionals, and are all therefore `.some`, so they are 'non-`nil`'. Try annotating the return of `flatMap(_:)` as `[String]` instead, like I showed in [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42213785/2976878).

Comment: Also see this other Q&A: [Swift flatMap on array with elements are optional has different behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37505787/2976878) (possible dupe?)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the definition of `flatMap()`

> `public func flatMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]`

When you set the type of `resultTypeSpecified` to `[String?]`, you tell the compiler that `ElementOfResult` is `Optional<String>`.

Your transform closure has a type of `(String?) -> Optional<Optional<String>>`.

`flatMap` will take away 1 "layer" of optionals but not 2 layers.

Hopefully this example will makes things clearer:

```
let input: [String??] = [
    Optional.some(Optional.some("1989")),
    Optional.some(Optional.none),
    Optional.some(Optional.some("Fearless")),
    Optional.some(Optional.none),
    Optional.some(Optional.some("Red"))
]

let output = input.flatMap({ $0 })
```